# Use of environment variables with Netlify and React(Gatsby)

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, gatsby, netlify

I'm using env variables in my react app, so I don't expose my private API keys publicly. They are set in a `.env` file (which is excluded from git) like so - `REACT_APP_ENV_NAME` which works fine during development.

I have added those to the Netlify env configuration from within the site settings panel, but they don't seem to work during production (just showing as undefined). Have any of you had the same problem before/managed to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GATSBY_` prefix in your environment variables. So, your `REACT_APP_ENV_NAME` will be `GATSBY_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME` in your Netlify back office.

You can check for further information in [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#example-of-using-an-environment-variable), in this [Netlify community thread](https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-access-environment-variables/1240) and in [Netlify documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/#gatsby).

From [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#example-of-using-an-environment-variable):

> Please note that you shouldn’t commit .env.* files to your source
>   control and rather use options given by your Continuous Deployment
>   (CD) provider. An example is Netlify with its build environment
>   variables.
>
> `GATSBY_API_URL=https://dev.example.com/api 
>   API_KEY=927349872349798`

From [Netlify documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/#gatsby):

> **Gatsby environment variables**
>
> Any environment variables prefixed with `GATSBY_` will be processed by
>   Gatsby and made available in the browser for client-side JavaScript
>   access. Visit the Gatsby docs about environment variables for more
>   information.